# How to use OCMock to mock a service

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am trying to write a unit test for creating a checklistItem, with properties defined below:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, ChecklistStatus) { Pending, Completed };
@protocol IChecklistItem <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSInteger Id;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *Description;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly)BOOL IsCompleted;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) ChecklistStatus Status;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSDate *CompletedDate;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *CompletedByUserId;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSInteger RoleId;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSInteger GroupId;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray<IChecklistNote> *Notes;
```

Right now I have this setup in my setup method in my XCTest:

`_service = [[ChecklistService alloc]initWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:kcChecklistUrl] credentialsManager:self.credentialsManager];`

And this is the rest of my Unit Test:

```
- (void)testCreateChecklistItem {
    XCTAssertNotNil(_service);
    CCChecklistItem *checklistItem = [CCChecklistItem new];
    CCChecklistItem *newChecklistItem = [CCChecklistItem new];
    newChecklistItem.Id = 2;
    newChecklistItem.Description = @"This is the Description";
    newChecklistItem.RoleId = 2;
    newChecklistItem.GroupId = 3;
    newChecklistItem.Notes = nil;
    newChecklistItem.Status = Completed;

    XCTestExpectation *checklistItemExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"checklistItem"];

    id delegate = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(ChecklistServiceDelegate));
    id mock = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:(@protocol(IChecklistService))];
    [[[mock stub] andReturn:newChecklistItem] createChecklistItem:checklistItem delegate:delegate];

    OCMExpect(([delegate didCompleteCreateChecklistItem:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj) {
        CCChecklistItem *items = obj;
        XCTAssertNotNil(items);
        double checklistId = items.Id;
        XCTAssert(checklistId != 0);
        [checklistItemExpectation fulfill];
    }]]));

    [_service createChecklistItem:checklistItem delegate:delegate];
    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler:^(NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
        }
        OCMVerifyAll(delegate);
    }];
}
```

However, i get the error `failed: caught "NSUnknownKeyException", "[<__NSCFString 0x7faeaad6bd60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CompletedBy."`

The createChecklistItem is defined below:

```
- (void)createChecklistItem:(id<IChecklistItem>)checklistItem delegate:(NSObject<ChecklistServiceDelegate> *)delegate
{
    NSMutableArray *mockChecklistItem = [NSMutableArray new];
    [TestObjectLoader loadObject:mockChecklistItem
                    fromJSONFile:@"ChecklistItem"
                     withMapping:[MappingProvider checklistCreateMapping]];
    if (delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector (didCompleteCreateChecklistItem:)]) {
        [delegate didCompleteCreateChecklistItem:(NSObject<IChecklistItem> *)mockChecklistItem];
    }
}
```

Where Checklist.json is

```
{
    "Id": 13,
    "Desc": "Checklist Description",
    "IsCompleted": "false",
    "TypeId": 1,
    "RoleId": 1,
    "Status": "C",
    "CompletedDateTime": "2015-06-23T00:00:00+00:00",
    "CompletedBy": "AC",
    "Notes": [
              {
              "Note": "test",
              "CreatedBy": "AC",
              "CreatedDateTime": "2015-06-23T00:00:00+00:00"
              }
              ]
}
```

Basically, I want to mock the service and when `createChecklistItem` is called, I simply just want to set a random Id on the object and pass it back instead of reading it through the ChecklistService from the Json file. IS there anyway to do this? I incorporated the mock in my test but I do not believe i am using it correctly...

Comment: This is a lot of code. Could you provide a reduced version or at least a stack trace for when the exception occurs? Given that the exception complains about `NSString` not being KV compliant for the `CreatedBy` property it seems like there is an issue when the JSON is mapped into the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need `Checklist.json`, you should just be returning a value with a different Id.

So...

```
- (void)createChecklistItem:(id<IChecklistItem>)checklistItem delegate:(NSObject<ChecklistServiceDelegate> *)delegate
{
    NSMutableArray *mockChecklistItem = [NSMutableArray new];
    [TestObjectLoader loadObject:mockChecklistItem
                    fromJSONFile:@"ChecklistItem"
                     withMapping:[MappingProvider checklistCreateMapping]];
    if (delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector (didCompleteCreateChecklistItem:)]) {
        [delegate didCompleteCreateChecklistItem:(NSObject<IChecklistItem> *)mockChecklistItem];
    }
}
```

should simply just be

```
checklistItem.Id = 2; //Random number
```